# Will a bullet dropped and a bullet fired from a gun horizontally REALLY hit the ground at the same time when air drag is taken into account?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile, drag

In a world without air, I understand they definitely would. However, with drag taken into account, I think they wouldn't. Since the drag force varies proportional to the square of speed (ignoring the change in coefficient of drag with speed), wouldn't the total impulse due to drag on a bullet fired from a gun from a specific height horizontal to ground be higher than the total impulse on an identical bullet dropped from the same height with no horizontal velocity?

Also, when bullet spin is taken into account, the bullet fired from a gun should resist change in orientation; therefore, it should maintain a small but non-zero angle of attack, and also have a lift force, correct?

Comment: I don't see how the spin or the drag would create lift. Can you spell out in more detail why you think it would?

Comment: Also, have you seen this test? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9wQVIEdKh8

Comment: @BrandonEnright Spin on a bullet causes resistance to change in orientation, so as the bullet follows a downward trajectory, instead of simply pointing in the direction of its velocity vector, it will point slightly upward relative to it because of the resistance to change (because of spin). It should have a non-zero angle of attack due to this, and therefore have a lift force. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @BrandonEnright Yeah, I have. I agree that the difference in time for the two bullets will be so tiny that it doesn't even really matter. I'm just asking if there would be a tiny difference.

Comment: I think there would be a (tiny) difference for a rapidly spinning bullet that is dropped versus a randomly tumbling bullet that is dropped simply because as you state, a spinning bullet resists orientation changes.  I don't think this difference is enough to be meaningful in real world situations though.  I seriously doubt a bullet fired from a gun would have a positive angle of attack that would allow it to convert forward motion into lift.

Comment: @BrandonEnright I know it wouldn't when it comes out of the barrel, but through its trajectory the velocity vector should point more and more towards ground, and I feel that the angle of attack should increase (extremely) slightly through its trajectory. And, yeah, I know it's not a practically meaningful difference :) just a question of understanding.

Comment: It doesn't have to change orientation to change direction of travel.

Comment: @Polyergic Exactly; assuming it doesn't tumble, that's why I think it should also have a tiny lift force as well. Because it doesn't have to change orientation, it should end up pointing higher than it's velocity vector.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your hypothesis.  It makes sense now, but I think that the angle would be too small to get lift until it's already slowed too much to transfer any energy.  (Or fallen too far to be in air.)  You might be able to calculate a difference, but I don't think it would just be too small to matter, I think it would be too small to be meaningful under the model used.  Something like, assume air is continuous, and get a result smaller than the influence of one air molecule.

Comment: I think the usual interpretation of the question involves a simple (smooth bore) gun, not a rifle.  The MythBusters video Brandon linked appears to use a simple gun.  Still, if you let them fall far enough, aerodynamic differences between going point-first and side-first might change their falling times.  To get a really pure answer, you'd need spherical bullets.  But we can't quite make those.

Comment: I have the impression that the advantage of spinning a bullet is that it will fly straighter through real air (with wind and whatnot), so I wonder if the thing to do would be to show that the lift can be written with the same expression that describes the resistance to a crosswind.  The Wikipedia page on rifling is interesting, but doesn't have enough information.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rifling

Comment: @ShadSterling bb guns?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just based on the quadratic drag of air, yes, the fired bullet would take longer to hit the ground.

Just consider the vertical force caused by the air friction:

$F_y = - F_{\rm drag} \sin \theta = - C (v_x^2 + v_y^2) \frac{v_y}{\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}} = - C v_y \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}$

Where $\theta$ is the angle above the horizon for the bullet's velocity, and $C$ is some kind of drag coefficient. Note that when the bullet is moving down $\theta$ is negative, as is $v_y$, so the overall vertical force is positive and keeps the bullet off the ground for slightly longer.

In the dropped case, $v_x = 0$, so we get $F_y = -C v_y^2$.

In the fired case, we can neglect $v_y$ in the radical (assuming it's much smaller than $v_x$) and we get $F_y \approx -C v_y |v_x|$.

In other words, **the upward force on the fired bullet is stronger**, by a factor of $v_x / v_y$.

So freshman-level physics is wrong, at least according to sophomore-level physics.

---

**Bonus Case:**

If you're assuming a flat surface *on earth*, it's worth considering that many "flat" things (like the ocean) actually curve down and drop off below the horizon. In case you want to account for this curvature, it may be worth going to the bullet's reference frame with $\hat{y}$ always defined to point away from the center of the earth. Note that this puts you in a rotating reference frame, and then look at the centrifugal "force":

$F_y = m a = m R \omega^2 = m R \left(\frac{v_x}{R}\right)^2 = m \frac{v_x^2}{R} $

Where $R$ is the radius of the earth and $m$ is the mass of the bullet. So again, an upward force, this time proportional to $v_x$ squared. Of course this is the same as pointing out that the earth curves away from a straight line, but it's another fun application of not-quite-freshman physics.

---

Now you can add in much more complicated aerodynamics, but there the question sort of looses its undergrad physics charm there and becomes an aerospace engineering question!

Comment: Now wait a second, you're not suggesting that the "v" in the formula for drag is the magnitude of the velocity, right? Because I'm pretty sure if I fired a bullet straight downward, the drag force in the horizontal direction would be zero...

Comment: Yeah, v is velocity, but I'm not giving an equation for horizontal force. The assumption is that horizontal force won't affect the time for the bullet to hit the ground. What is the problem?

Comment: ... or to be more precise, the horizontal force _will_ affect the time for the bullet to hit the ground in that it modifies v_x, but the point is that the vertical force in the fired case is always greater than in the dropped case.

Comment: I do not think your first equation is correct. The drag force in the y-direction should only depend on the velocity in the y-direction, which is the same for both cases. I'll do another answer. I admit to not being an expert, perhaps we can reason it out.

Comment: what you say is only true in the linear drag case (which dominates in, for example, most biophysics applications). In the case of quadratic drag it breaks down.

Comment: Problem with this line of thought is that from an **experimental** standpoint, and when the bullet starts from an height from ground commensurate to a man's size, the effect of $F_y$ on the time it takes for the bullet to reach ground is negligible in both the case of the bullet dropped, and the case of the bullet fired. In the first case, the overwhelming factor is the drop height. In the second case, that's the (practically unavoidable) vertical component of the bullet's initial velocity, and the height.

Comment: FYI, coming from a years of making long-range shots: When doing *very* long range shots (over 2km, for example) this sort of thing actually starts to matter. The influence of humidity, temperature (on the barrel, in the powder chamber, of the projectile, and in the air), windage, elevation, angle of the shot, etc. are more significant, though, which is why it is always necessary to dope the gun in the area you are making huge shots. Also, most bullet drag profiles/models are way off from the actual bullet being fired, which is a much bigger influence when firing through transsonic phase.

Comment: I completely agree with @fgrieu: in reality it's going to be very hard or impossible to measure anything like this effect. Just the turbulence associated with something traveling 1 km a second is liable to wash out any measurable effect. But the OP asked about quadratic drag specifically (and lift associated with the shape of the bullet, but that's going to be very complicated), not a situation where every experimental uncertainty was taken into account. But yeah, in the experimental case I completely agree, this would be _very_ difficult to measure.

Comment: Very nice answer. One suggestion - pictures almost always help. This is one such time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't deal with drag forces often, but I think the equation for drag is

$$F_D=Cv^2,$$

where $F_D$ is in the same direction as $v$, and $C$ contains all the various things – density of air, cross-section, drag coefficient, etc. Importantly, $C$ **depends on the orientation of the object**. What I am going to do is assume the bullet falls without rotating – so it stays parallel to the ground during its entire motion (in both cases you drop it in the same direction you shoot it).

In the first case the equation of motion is found via Newton's second law:

$$\Sigma F_y=F_{D,y}-F_g=ma_y\rightarrow a_y=\frac{C_yv_y^2}{m}-g$$

In the second case, we need to consider both directions:

$$\Sigma F_y=F_{D,y}-F_g=ma_y\rightarrow a_y=\frac{C_yv_y^2}{m}-g$$
$$\Sigma F_x=-F_{D,x}=ma_x\rightarrow a_x=-\frac{C_xv_x^2}{m}$$

So to find the time of flight of either case one would have to integrate the $y$ equation, but in either case it is the same. Therefore, **the time of flight for these two situations is the same**. But of course, I'm assuming the bullet does not rotate during its motion.

If it *did* rotate, then the value of $C$ would be constant – it would be $C_x$, because that's the direction of motion – and $F_D$ would be in the direction of motion of the bullet, and $v$ would be the speed. In this case I believe the other answer would be correct, and they would reach the ground at different times.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for it to be calculated by component, because then the net drag force would be calculated to be different numbers in different reference frames. It is definitely the magnitude. And, there is no contradiction; the drag force is parallel and opposite the velocity. If there is no motion along the x axis, there will be no force along the x axis.

Comment: Well forces being different in different reference frames is not a problem. If it's "definitely the magnitude", then I think we need to know if the bullet turns while falling. Specifically, I agree that the drag force opposite the direction of motion should be dependent on the speed - but if the bullet doesn't turn while falling, then the drag force in the y-direction will be $C_yv^2$, whereas if it turns it will be $Cv^2sin\theta$, as in the other answer.

Comment: you can only separate the drag forces into components when you're dealing with linear drag, you're doing something wrong between your first and second equations

Comment: You're wrong in assuming you can calculate the force in the x and y directions independently. Your argument for it doesn't quite work, because the force in the horizontal direction is not $c|v|^2$. That's the magnitude of the total drag force applied to the bullet, but the direction of the force is always opposite to the bullet's direction of motion (relative to the air), so in the case of a dropped bullet, the vertical component is $-c|v|^2$, and the horizontal component is zero.

Comment: The value for $C$ is different for our different cases, and that's my mistake. I'm assuming the bullet is falling like you dropped it horizontally - I'll correct it so the answer is clear in my assumptions.